# How to separate out real and imaginary terms

Tags: complex-numbers

I have an equation like this: 
$$a+ib = \log(x+iy).$$

I need to separate the real and imaginary part in RHS so that I can equate the real part of LHS to real part of RHS and imaginary to imaginary part of RHS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert the complex number from algebraic to polar form $r\cdot e^{j\theta} $ where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} $ and $\theta=\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) $

After that, you can split the $\log$ function into real and imaginary parts:

$$ \log(r\cdot e^{j\theta}) =\log(r) +j\theta\log(e) $$
$$ = \log(r) +j\theta $$ (assuming natural logarithm)

Answer (score 4):

Note your equation is equivalent to

$$
e^{a+jb}=a+jb\\
e^ae^{jb}=a+jb\\
e^a(\cos(b)+j\sin(b))=a+jb
$$
Then real and imaginary parts have been separated.

Comment: OP has changed the variables in his post (and it makes sense this now).

Comment: That I know but how do I seperate it in real and imaginary part when the complex number is inside a log funciton?. In the above equation forget the LHS. I need to solve the RHS $\log\(x+jy\)$ and  seperate this into the form a + jb